# Paper canvas size changes on opening of developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, paperjs

My problem is the following (using Paper.js).

I try to display a grid on a canvas, but it does not display the right way. My canvas size is set to 1600 X 800 pixels and on page load, it is in fact the size. Also, I have a loop for drawing the the grid lines, and I have made sure that the loop really iterate from 0 to 800px and 0 to 1600px :

```
var gridInfo = {size : 10, opacity : 0.7, strokeWidth :0.3, color : 'black'};
function(canvasHeight, canvasWidth, gridInfo){
    console.log("Creating Grid");
    for (var i = 0; i <= canvasWidth; i+= gridInfo.size){
        var from = new paper.Point(i, 0);
        var to = new paper.Point(i,canvasHeight);
        var gridPath = new paper.Path.Line(from,to);
        gridPath.strokeColor = gridInfo.color;
        gridPath.opacity = gridInfo.opacity;
        gridPath.strokeWidth = gridInfo.strokeWidth;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= canvasHeight; i+= gridInfo.size){
        var from = new paper.Point(0,i);
        var to = new paper.Point(canvasWidth,i);
        var gridPath = new paper.Path.Line(from,to);
        gridPath.strokeColor = gridInfo.color;
        gridPath.opacity = gridInfo.opacity;
        gridPath.strokeWidth = gridInfo.strokeWidth;
        floorPlanGrid.push(gridPath);
    }
}
```

I have initialized the `paper` variable to a new `PaperScope`. Here is the result for the (which illustrates the problem (right after loading the page) : 
[image]

So you can see on the bottom and right edges that the grid doesn't go all the way to the edge. The dimension of the canvas is in fact 1600px by 800px, and I confirmed that the loops for the grid really iterate from 0 to 800px and 0 to 1600px as I said. Finally, the problem goes away when I press F12 for dev tools (on Chrome). The grid then is the way I want (all over the canvas) and stays like that until I refresh the page. Here is the result after that :
[image]
Now the grid goes all the way to the edges, not perfect but satisfactory for me. Of course, what I want is the get the second result at the page loading, without having to open the dev tools. I have tried using the view.draw() function but it didn't do anything. Maybe it has to do something with the resize property of the canvas, which is triggered on devTools opening, but not after drawing the grid, but I don't know.

Thanks for the help. I'm not sure if I gave all the information to help you, tell me if there some more you would need!

Answer (score 1):

If it could help anyone with that, I finally managed to figure it out. It all had to do with the `paper.view.Size` was not the same as the canvas size (for a reason I ignore). So what I did was use the `paper.view.setViewSize(theWidth, theHeight)` function to force the view to the same size as the canvas, right before drawing the grid lines.